# VSFTPD permissions error. Can't create directory through Wordpress

Tags: permissions, ftp, vsftpd, wordpress

I've vsftpd user `dev` which is the member of `www-data`. Every file I upload through ftp gets `dev` as owner and `www-data` as a group. I can access the website through the browser and able to login and make content changes in the Wordpress backend. But It gives me a permission error `Cannot Create Directory` when I try to install Theme or Plugin.
Everytime I've to change the folder and files ownership to `www-data` user to make it work.

Please help me to solve this hurdle.

Comment: did you set the `vsftpd.conf` well

Comment: what I did in addition to setting up the `vsftpd.conf` I created a replica of my   dev folder in `/home/$USER` then i added this in my `/etc/fstab` `/var/www/html   /home/george/www none bind 0 0` so its mounted at boot. I now access it from wordpress and so development as though on the web

Comment: @George in `vsftpd.conf` I set it to `local_umask=022`

Comment: Did you setup the `SSL Certificates, write_enable=YES, local_enable=YES`?

Comment: I didn't setup the `SSL Certificates` but yes `write_enable=YES, local_enable=YES` is there.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue. Check that `user` and `group` in /etc/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf are set to `www-data`. By default it's `http`.